# Combine regexs to contain certain characters and ignore special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two expressions:

1) `/\W/` to remove any special characters (except underscore _).

2) `/lorem/` - String must contain lorem.

Can I combine those 2 regexps into 1 regex?

So for example, if run against `l-orem`, regex must match because it contains lorem and hyphen will be ignored.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `lorem` should be one word?

Comment: Your two steps would seem to already give you the logic you need.  What then is the problem?

Comment: Try: `l\W*o\W*r\W*e\W*m`

Comment: @gurvinder372 yes

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how do I make those 2 into 1 single regex. That's what I was asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining both regex will look like this:

```
/.*l\W*o\W*r\W*e\Wl.*/
```

(^that's a javascript regex. In Java, one wouldn't need slashes at the beginning and end).

Answer (score 2):

You could make it in steps:

```
var str = 'l-orem';
str.replace(/\W/g, '').match(/lorem/); // ['lorem']

var str = 'l-oram';
str.replace(/\W/g, '').match(/lorem/); // null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following codes depending on your exact needs (depending on if you need to remove `_` or not, beware `\W` will not remove it, and depending on if you want a case sensitive match or not)

```js
var str = '123l-orem';
console.log(/lorem/.test(str.replace(/\W/g, ''))); //true
console.log(/lorem/.test(str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,''))); //true

var str = 'll_oremm';
console.log(str.replace(/\W/g, '').match(/lorem/)); //beware here!!!! -> null
console.log(str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,'').match(/lorem/)); //lorem 
console.log(/lorem/.test(str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,'')));

var str = 'L_-O&R@E^MmMm%';
console.log(str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,'').match(/lorem/)); //null
console.log(str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,'').match(/lorem/i));  //LOREM
console.log(/lorem/i.test(str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,''))); //true

var str = 'a_b-^c123';
console.log(str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,'').match(/lorem/)); //null
console.log(str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,'').match(/lorem/i)); //null
console.log(/lorem/i.test(str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]+/gi,''))); //false
```